# Reserved words for CloudFormation templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Are there reserved words, variables, etc for CloudFormation templates?  I've specified a DynamoDB table called "Config":

```
  # ...standard CF definition
  Resources:
    # ...other resources that correctly build
    Config:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: my-app-config
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: name
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: name
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

...and applied the template, but the resource is not being created.  I don't see any errors in the CloudFormation console.

Comment: Your table name is `my-app-config`

Answer (score 1):

The name of your resource (`Config`) should not cause any problems.

The `Config` resource must be nested under a `Resources` object, like this:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: My Stack

Resources:
  Config:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: my-app-config
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: name
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: name
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: Thanks @spg, it is correctly under Resources, I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Just so you know, I successfully created a stack using the snipped in my answer. Either the DynamoDB table is created and you can't find it (are you looking at a different AWS region by mistake?), or the error stems from another part of the CloudFormation template you're not showing.

Comment: Thanks @spg, I agree it's probably another error.  Not sure what it is yet